# Two Ajax in same page one not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have 2 ajax call in same page. first one is working fine but second not,

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".setDefault").click(function(){         
        var shipId=$(".setDefault:checked").val();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "ajx-scripts.php",
             data: {shippingId:shipId},
             success: function(data) {
            }
        });
    });
    $(".remove-address").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("value");
        alert(id);
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "ajx-scripts.php",
             data: {shipId:id},
             success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

alert of id is working. shipId and shippingId are different

ajx-scripts.php  is as below

```
if(isset($_POST["shippingId"])){
    $shippingId=$_POST["shippingId"];
    $rslt=mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_shipping_addresses AS s, (SELECT fkCustomer FROM tbl_shipping_addresses WHERE shippingId='$shippingId') AS p SET s.setDefault='0' WHERE s.fkCustomer=p.fkCustomer");
    mysql_query("update tbl_shipping_addresses set setDefault=1 where shippingId='$shippingId'");
 }

if(isset($_POST["shipId"])){
    $shippingId=$_POST["shipId"];
    $rslt=mysql_query("select fkCustomer from tbl_shipping_addresses where shippingId='$shippingId'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt);
    $customer=$row['fkCustomer'];
    mysql_query("delete from tbl_shipping_addresses where shippingId='$shippingId'");
    echo "deleted";
}
```

Comment: Have you checked exactly where this request is failing? Is it on the server or the client? Is the request being sent at all? What's the value of `id`?

Comment: How would you say that its not working? Do you have any error?

Comment: are shippingId and shipId different? second ajax must be returning error from server code. can you debug it?

Comment: i'm beginner in ajax, id value is number, it alerts correct, i think the request not reach in ajx-scripts.php

Comment: shippingId and shipId ara different

Answer (score 1):

There is different parameter for both. If you are checking the send data parameter for both index then it should work else it should be problem.

In second ajax call try this:

```
data: {shippingId:id},
```

instead of

```
data: {shipId:id},
```

Hope so there will be problem.

You can also check the error in the ajax call by adding `.error` function like this:

```
$(".remove-address").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("value");
    alert(id);
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ajx-scripts.php",
         data: {shippingId:id},
         success: function(data) {
             alert(data);
        },
        error: function(x,a,y){ //add this error function
            alert(JSON.stringify(x)+" "+a);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @user3030589 means your ajax working fine. have you try to replace the data which I have mention in answer.

Comment: They _do_ check for different parameters (see the PHP code).